# Codename One createMaterial icon size for a command

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to use a material FontImage for a Command in the Toolbar. That works, but I don't know how to change the size of the image. I can't find a way to do that with the Style since it has no style option.
I found out I can change the fontsize with this:

```
style.setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_LARGE));
FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, style);
```

But how to change it to for example pixels?

Answer (score 1):

The size is determined from the Style in the theme.

Although you can also change the height using derive:

```
style.setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_LARGE).derive(fontHeight, Font.STYLE_PLAIN));
FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, style);
```

You can set the size in pixels using:

```
FontImage icon = FontImage.createFixed("" + FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS, FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont(), colorRGB, widthPixels, heightPixels);
```

But the best way to set it is using:

```
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(myComponent, FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS);
```

This is the **best** approach because the icon will derive the style from your component (font size, foreground color etc.) which means you don't really need to do anything for this to work and your offhand style customization will implicitly be applied.

Comment: Thank you! I want to use the last mentioned way (setMaterialIcon method), but myComponent can not be a Command, only a Label, MultiButton or SpanButton?